# Fire a typed scroll when it is a certain time of the day

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-events

Certain event to fire off at a certain time of day, as you can see below, more than likely a mess, I am trying to have it at a certain time fire off the good morning typed.js and then when it is another time of the day I want the good afternoon one to fire off, I plan on adding more, but not until I can figure out how to get this to work. On it's own it works fine, but when I try to add it to work with the time of the day, I just cannot figure it out. I have searched all over the internet and tried combining one's I read about, but no luck. So this is my last hope..

EDITED: NEW CODE

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 function timeToScroll(){
    var currentHour = getHours();
    var yes = true;

var x = $('#cursing').typed({
        strings:["Good morning and welcome to my", "Buenos días y bienvenidos a mi","Bom dia e boas-vindas ao meu","Guten Morgen und herzlich willkommen auf meiner", "早上好，欢迎来到我的", "おはようございますとへようこそ私", "Доброе утро и добро пожаловать в мой", "Tere hommikust ja tere tulemast minu"],
        typeSpeed: 1,
        backDelay: 3000,
        loop: true,
        loopCount: 500
    });
var y = $('#cursing').typed({
        strings:["GOOD AFTERNOON and welcome to my", "Buenos días y bienvenidos a mi","Bom dia e boas-vindas ao meu","Guten Morgen und herzlich willkommen auf meiner", "早上好，欢迎来到我的", "おはようございますとへようこそ私", "Доброе утро и добро пожаловать в мой", "Tere hommikust ja tere tulemast minu"],
        typeSpeed: 1,
        backDelay: 3000,
        loop: true,
        loopCount: 500
    });

    if(yes == true) {
        alert("Well Atleast we know it works");

    } else {
        document.write(y);
    }
}
});
```

Comment: If statements are written as `if (cond) { . . . } else if (cond) { . . . }`

Comment: Hmm, since you add the hour to the minutes, won't that mean it'll only be able to trigger a few mins each hour? Wouldn't hour alone suffice to check if the current time is between 5AM and 16PM ? As a sidenote, it's probably way better to only save the string if that's the only difference bwteen the .typed calls, atm you duplicate the function call for each condition.

Comment: @gcampbell Yes sorry I originally had them when I was trying to beautify it and copy it over here it got deleted.. both the { } are in it, it still does not work... I am combining jQuery and JavaScript and I just do not know how to do that and cannot figure this damn thing out, been working on it for hours...

Comment: @Shilly You are right, I deleted the get minutes method and am just using the getHours, still does not seem to work, once I figure this out the text will be completely different, I do not fully follow what you mean by save the string and duplicate the call for each condition? do you mean save them in a variable and them pull them up by calling the var name?

Comment: Hmm, some notes. Does your interval have a duration as the second parameter? If not, it won't run. An interval would check the time every x miliseconds, so the .typed() function can keep triggering every x miliseconds. If you only need to trigger it once, when the site opens, you don't need an interval. Note that intervals stop working once the browser window loses focus, so when a user opens a second page, your interval timer will pause. Could you update your code so it's easier to check for errors? Also try replacing the .typed function call with just alert or log to check the if/else logic.

Comment: Okay so I changed the code to this now, and I do not get an alert nor do i get the type.js function happen... My inspect on chrome does not throw any flags up for errors in javascript so I really don't know why this is not working here is the new code... Edited original code with the newest one..

Comment: You can look at the source on my github, maybe that might help? https://github.com/KangOnRails/Portfolio-PHP